# Drag and drop not working (menu item) android studio

Tags: android-studio, drag-and-drop, menuitem

Everything is working fine, however drag and drop is not working while editing menu items, every time I drag an item and drop it inside menu, that is being created, is not added up. 
I am using android studio (info):

[image: about]

But adding item by xml like:

`<item android:title="Settings"></item>`

is working perfectly, any idea how to fix it?

Another screenshot of my Android Studio:

[image: android Studio]

Comment: @Billa center of what, menu? Not working as well.

Comment: read the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version of android studio uses 2 xml files for each layout. One (e.g. content_main.xml) embedded in the other one (Activity_main.xml). you should open the content_*.xml and do the design in it. hope it helps.

In your code segment the menu is not inside [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgFkL.jpg).I think it must be inside layout under activiymain.

Comment: I am not sure where to edit, where will I get the other xml file?

Comment: is menu an activity in your app?

Comment: If menu under layout, I think you can drag and drop palette

Comment: Actually I had to drag and drop item inside the menu, means visible items on the menu layout, I was trying to add it inside component tree, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding something on activity_main.xml instead of main.xml